# Why is my array only returning the last row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have searched the site, but can not find the answer or how it would relate to how I have my query set up. Here is my file that processing my post data and passes to db. I have form that is wrapped around a table. The cells in the table are populated by an array. When I leave this page I want the values in the table cells written to a new table in the db. Each row in the table represents a separate row in the db.

Here is my form where all my post data is coming from.

```
    <form action="post_movement.php?class_id=<?php echo $class_id; ?>&pagenum=<?php echo $pagenum; ?>" method="post">
     <table border=1 width=800px>
 <tr>
 <th width=300px>Client</th>
 <th width=50px>Order</th>
 <th width=200px>Movements</th>
 <th>Sets/Reps/Seconds</th>  
 <th width=150px>Rest</th>
 <th>X Completed</th>
 </tr>

<?php

// Get workout class and output in table format -------------------------------------------------

if(empty($workout_class) === false)
{   
foreach($workout_class as $wc){
if ($wc['pagenum'] !== $pagenum) continue 1;

    echo '<tr>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="first_name[]" value="'.($wc['first_name']).'">'. ($wc['first_name']).'
        <span><input type="hidden" name="nickname[]" value="'.($wc['nickname']).'">('. ($wc['nickname']).')</span>
        <span><input type="hidden" name="last_name[]" value="'.($wc['last_name']).'">'. ($wc['last_name']).'</span>
        </td>
              <td><input type="hidden" name="order[]" value="'.($wc['order']).'">'. ($wc['order']). '</td>
              <td>
              <select name="movement[]" width=200>
              <option>'. ($wc['mv_00']). '</option>
              <option>'. ($wc['mv_01']). '</option>
              <option>'. ($wc['mv_02']). '</option>
              <option>'. ($wc['mv_03']). '</option>
              <option>'. ($wc['mv_04']). '</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="rep_set_sec[]" value="'.($wc['rep_set_sec']).'">'. ($wc['rep_set_sec']). '</td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="rest[]" value="'.($wc['rest']).'">'. ($wc['rest']). '</td>
        <td>00</td>
        </tr>';
  } // foreach($data_array
    //print_r($data_array);
} // if(!empty

?>

<! End Table ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Complete Movement">

</form>
```

Here is my php that process the post data from the form and submits it to the query.

```
    if (empty($_POST)=== false){
$movement_data = array('user_id', 'class_id', 'class_name', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'nickname', 'order', 'movement', 'rep_set_sec', 'rest', 'date');
foreach($movement_data as $key => $value){
     $movement_data = array(
        'user_id'   => $session_user_id,
        'class_id'  => $_GET['class_id'],
        'class_name'    => $class_name,
        'first_name'    => $_POST['first_name'],
        'last_name'     => $_POST['last_name'],
        'nickname'  => $_POST['nickname'],
        'order'     => $_POST['order'],
        'movement'  => $_POST['movement'],
        'rep_set_sec'   => $_POST['rep_set_sec'],
        'rest'      => $_POST['rest'],
        'date'      => $today
        );
    }

    completed_movement($movement_data);
    //header('Location: new_client.php');
    //exit ();

    }
```

Here is my query that inserts the POST data into db.

```
    function completed_movement($movement_data){
array_walk($movement_data, 'array_sanitize');

$fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($movement_data)) . '`';
$data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $movement_data) . '\'';


$query = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `completed_movements` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");

}
```

HTML form page has two table rows of data and looks like this.

```
    Colby (Big Cheese) Dodson | 1A | Key Movement | Sets/Reps/Seconds | Rest|
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Mike (Big Mac) Mckenzie   | 1A | Key Movement | Sets/Reps/Seconds | Rest|
```

A var_dump ($_POST) produces this. I can see that value in there just not sure if it looks like its supposed to.

```
    array(7) { 
           ["first_name"]=> array(2) { 
               [0]=> string(5) "Colby" 
               [1]=> string(4) "Mike" } 
           ["nickname"]=> array(2) { 
               [0]=> string(10) "Big Cheese" 
               [1]=> string(7) "Big Mac" } 
           ["last_name"]=> array(2) { 
               [0]=> string(6) "Dodson" 
               [1]=> string(8) "McKenzie" } 
           ["order"]=> array(2) { 
               [0]=> string(2) "1A" 
               [1]=> string(2) "1A" } 
           ["movement"]=> array(2) { 
               [0]=> string(12) "Key Movement" 
               [1]=> string(12) "Key Movement" } 
           ["rep_set_sec"]=> array(2) { 
               [0]=> string(17) "Sets/Reps/Seconds" 
               [1]=> string(17) "Sets/Reps/Seconds" } 
           ["rest"]=> array(2) { 
               [0]=> string(4) "Rest" 
               [1]=> string(4) "Rest" } 
           }
```

Is this what its supposed to look like when it does the var_dump?

I need each row of my array to look like this. The first three values are the user_id, class_id, & class_name and are not part of my html form on the previous page. These vales are picked up on the parsing script page and passed along with each row of my results.

```
    $row = array(29, 48, Class 1, Colby, Big Cheese, Dodson, 1A, Key Movement, Sets/Reps/Secons, Rest)
```

I need a row like this for each entry from my form.

Comment: You are returning `$movement_data`, what are you trying to return?

Comment: What is this suppose to do: foreach($movement_data as $key => $value); ? Actually line 2 and 3 doesn't do anything

Comment: To increase readability, I would recommend wrapping the body of a loop with curly-braces.

Comment: `$movement_data = array(` this replaces the entire array.

Comment: My foreach takes all my post data from a form on a different page and inserts into db. I'll post my form above.

Comment: I have a form that is wrapped around an html table that the cell contents are populated with results from an array. When I leave that page I am trying to post the data in those table cells to a db with each new table row representing a new row of data in the table. Everything things seems to be working except for the fact that it only post the last row of data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query));
return $movement_data;

print_r($movement_data);
```

Your `while` loop goes through the whole array - there's no code evaluated. When it finishes, it returns the last value, because that's the only item in the variable. Your `print_r` is never going to be evaluated.

Editted to add:

```
foreach($movement_data as $key => $value);
```

There's also a trailing semicolon on your foreach statement. That will have the same result.

Editted, again:

Each form value is being passed as an array of values; so what you need to do is step through the arrays, and process them one by one. The code below should work, but I've not tested it.

It's looping on the `$_POST["first_name"]` array - for each of those values, it's populating a temporary array, and passing that to your function. Some of those values are hard-wired, and some are coming from the equivalent array index - the first run through uses the index elements with a value of 0, and so on.

```
$i = 0;
while (isset($_POST["first_name"][$i])) {
    $movement_data = array(   
        'user_id'   => $session_user_id,   
        'class_id'  => $_GET['class_id'],   
        'class_name'    => $class_name,   
        'first_name'    => $_POST['first_name'][$i],   
        'last_name'     => $_POST['last_name'][$i],   
        'nickname'  => $_POST['nickname'][$i],   
        'order'     => $_POST['order'][$i],   
        'movement'  => $_POST['movement'][$i],   
        'rep_set_sec'   => $_POST['rep_set_sec'][$i],   
        'rest'      => $_POST['rest'][$i],   
        'date'      => $today   
        );   

    completed_movement($movement_data);

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: You are re-setting `$movement_data` for each loop over `$movement_data`.

Comment: @Rocket - you know, I think I'll just remove that whole section. I can't figure out what he's trying to do, so I shall just point out the problems I know I can fix.

Comment: I have a form that is wrapped around an html table that the cell contents are populated with results from an array. When I leave that page I am trying to post the data in those table cells to a db with each new table row representing a new row of data in the table. Everything things seems to be working except for the fact that it only post the last row of data.

Comment: @Colbyd - then you need to get your loop working to go through each row. It won't work as it stands with the semicolon at the end of the line - that will just jump straight to the last entry.

Comment: @andrewsi I have edited my `foreach` statement above. Same result.

Comment: @Rocket Im not sure what you mean. Only been doing this a couple of months.

Comment: @Colbyd - you're re-setting `$movement_data` every time that loop runs

Comment: For another thing - you're only getting one set of data from your form. try a `var_dump($_POST)` at the top of your parsing script, so you can see exactly what's being passed it.

Comment: @andrewsi Ok I see now that only the last row of my table is being passed to my parsing script. What is it about my form/table that is only passing along he last row of data?

Comment: @colby - every line is in the style of `<input type="hidden" name="first_name"` - every iteration will have an entry called `first_name`, and when it's passed to the parser, the earlier iterations get over-written by the later ones.

Comment: @andrewsi Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @andrewsi Thanks for the link. I know can pass the post data to the parsing script and I can `print_r $movement_data` from the parsing script page as well. Now the only variable being passed to the sql query are the `$_GET` variables. Is my query set up wrong to work with my POST array like I have it?

Comment: @Colbyd - you shouldn't use both GET and POST in the same form - it's bad practice, as it makes it harder to work out what's being submitted.

Comment: They are not in the same form so to speak I am just using GET to pass class_id and pagenum from current page to db. I am not pulling GET data from my form on the previous page. If that is what you are talking about. Or is passing both GET and POST through an array a bad idea?

Comment: @Colbyd - You can include them as hidden fields and POST everything. You can certainly use both POST and GET, but it just makes things inconsistent.

Comment: @andrewsi Thanks for you help. Now to see if I can get my query to work.

Comment: @andrewsi I've got a new question. In trying to get the query to work I realized that none of the POST data is being passed to my `$movement_data` array. So I started trying a few things to see what I could get to return. I tried this `$comma_separated = implode(",", $_POST);
 echo ($comma_separated);` to see if I could get all the values to output. This is what I got back "Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array29,48,Class1,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,Array,12.08.17" The only variable that returned a value are the variables that are declared on the same page as my parsing scripts.

Comment: @andrewsi cont.... there are two table rows on previous page. So shouldn't received two complete rows of data?

Comment: @Colbyd - try `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's in there

Comment: @andrewsi I edited my code about to show what my html form page looks like when output to browser as well as what I get I do the var_dump.

Comment: @andrewsi if you get a chance will you take a look at the code i posted above. I know the problem I just dont know how to fix it. When passing `$movement_data` to my function to insert into db if I do a `print_r $data;` from my function I get 28, 48, Class 1, , , , , , , , 08202012. It's just getting the array and not the values inside the posted array.

Comment: @andrewsi....Perfect! Thank you so much! I was figuring what the problem was I just have a hard time related a solution to my problem. Thanks Again!